# How to call a foreign key from a foreign app where the key is non primary key in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-database, django-apps, python-django-storages

I started working on task tracker DB in Django. I have different apps like user, task,status etc., now I am trying to call userID in different app, which is actually an ID in user table (by default autogenerated column).

Below is example where I want to call ID from user app to Status app as userID:

```
from user.models import User
class Task(models.Model)
    userID = models.ForeignKey(User, to_field="id", db_column="userID",  default="", editable=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #Other fields
```

But I am getting this error in my terminal:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: foreign key mismatch - "status_status" referencing "user_user"
```

This is the [error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYgAa.png).

Also my table name is coming like `status_status`, `user_user`. What am I doing wrong?

User model code:

```
from django.db import models
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    band = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    team = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

And below is code for status model where I want to use id as foreign key:

```
from django.db import models
from user.models import User
class Status(models.Model):
    userID = models.ForeignKey(User, to_field="id", db_column="userID",  
                     default="",editable=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    startDate = models.DateTimeField()
    endDate = models.DateTimeField()
    remark = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

Comment: Can you share all of your models? Which command were you running when you generated the error?

Comment: @lain thanks for replying. By models you meant apps right? so, I have created 5 models user, task, status, Kra and KraSheet. Where I will going to require userId in task and status. I am able to run `python manage.py makemigrations (model_name)` for each models. But when I am running `python manage.py migrate` it is throwing me this error... Hope I am clear from my  end.

Comment: Can you paste the code for your status model in the question? That seems to be where the problem is

Comment: Default of blank string doesn’t make much sense for an integer column. Maybe make the foreign key nullable

Comment: still not working bro..@lain Shelvington

Comment: what is the databses backend name?